# why sqlalchemy expunge not work?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Here is my code:

```
class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'room'

    _id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


def create_room(self):
    try:
        session = Session()
        new_room = Room()
        session.add(new_room)
        session.expunge(new_room)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        return new_room
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        logger.error('create room error')
        logger.error(e)
        return None
```

I use expunge to detach the object from session, and then I print the room id:

```
room = room.create_room()
logger.info('room %d created' % room._id)
```

but the system said:

```
logger.info('room %d created' % room._id)
exceptions.TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Why is that happen?

Comment: you're adding new_room to the session and then expunge will remove the same instance, then commit will throw error, that's why you're getting room as `None`, which is why you're getting that TypeError

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this? Why do you want to expunge at all?

Comment: If I don't expunge it, I can not use it after committing session, and I don't want to keep the session because I have many rooms, if each room keeps a session, the session pool will be exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit or at least [flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) the session first, expunge later.

I suppose the room ID is generated by the database. If you expunge an object before committing, it's never inserted, and the ID is never generated and returned, so it remains `None`.

Comment: Can't you do several transactions in a session? You could want an object to participate in some and not in others, so you can add or expunge it at will. OTOH adding and expunging back makes little sense unless you commit, or at least flush; else no SQL for that object will ever be sent to the DB. Apparently autoflush is off for this session.

Comment: I've tried to commit and then expunge but there's another error: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Room at 0x10c153f10> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

Comment: I found a workround: 'session.commit()  print new_room._id session.expunge(new_room)'   print the id before expunge could make it work, but it's ugly.